# Inserting row via stored procedure (Informix)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

Is it possible to create a stored procedure which inserts a row into table with values taken from procedure parameters? I'm using Informix. :-(

Comment: It should be possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I've tried something like this:`CREATE PROCEDURE proc (a VARCHAR(8), b INTEGER, c INTEGER) INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (a,b,c); END PROCEDURE`, but I get a syntax error.

Comment: What client are you using to access the database? If you are using `isql` you will get that error when you try to create stored procedures.

Comment: I'm using SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.7.1. Database product version is 11.50.FC2.

Comment: @pavle-crnković that has to do with the use of `;` inside the **SPL** block. Check the edit answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show how you are creating the procedure and executing.

The example you give on the comment to the question works:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess pavle -

Database selected.

> CREATE TABLE tab1(
>       col1 VARCHAR(8),
>       col2 INTEGER,
>       col3 INTEGER
> );

Table created.

> CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (a VARCHAR(8), b INTEGER, c INTEGER)
>       INSERT INTO tab1 (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (a,b,c);
> END PROCEDURE;

Routine created.

> EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp1 ('test sp1',1,2);

Routine executed.

> SELECT * FROM tab1;


col1            col2        col3

test sp1           1           2

1 row(s) retrieved.

>

Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

On **SQuirreL** you have to change the **Statement Separator** to something else temporarily.

Go to the **File** menu and select **New Session Properties**, go to the **SQL** tab and change the **Statement Separator** for something like `\`.

Connect again and try:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (a VARCHAR(8), b INTEGER, c INTEGER)
       INSERT INTO tab1 (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (a,b,c);
 END PROCEDURE\
```